# How to set a dropdown menu in the Alert Controller? Swift 5

Tags: swift, dropdown, alert

I have the following code which works very well, however I would like the second text field ("What is the priority?") to be a drop-down menu selection, of numbers 1-5, instead of allowing the user to input it.

```
// Create alert controller
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Project", message: "Begin an empty project here.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // add textfield at index 0
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Project Name"
    })

    // add textfield at index 1
    alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "What is the Priority (1-5)?"
    })

    // Alert action confirm
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Project", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("action confirmed")
    })
    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    
    // Alert action cancel
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present alert controller
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAlertController` doesn't have any support for adding menus. Its public API only supports adding buttons via `UIAlertAction` and adding text fields.

One workaround these limitations is to add a `UIButton` as the text field's `rightView` (or `leftView`). Setup the button with a menu containing 5 actions for the 5 possible values.

```
alertController.addTextField(configurationHandler: {(_ textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = "Priority"
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
    button.menu = UIMenu(children: (1...5).map({ num in
        UIAction(title: String(num)) { action in
            textField.text = String(num)
        }
    }))
    button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    textField.rightView = button
    textField.rightViewMode = .always
})
```

The text field is still editable but the user can select a value from the menu presented when the button is tapped.

If desired, there are tricks to make the text field read-only while still allowing the button to work. You would need to set the text field's `delegate` and return `false` from the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method. You can find plenty of existing questions covering that detail.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried out this code yet but once I get a chance to, I'm marking yours as the answer anyway.

Comment: hello. i got backward this error when trying this code "menu' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer".